# Google colab file download failed to fetch error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I used google colab to make a dictionary, dump it into a json file and download the file into my laptop by this code:

```
from google.colab import files
import json

dict = {'apple': 'fruit', 'mango': 'fruit', 'carrot': 'vegetable', 'brocoli': 'vegetable', 'cat': 'animal'}

with open('sampleDictionary.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(dict, f)

files.download('sampleDictionary.json')
f.close()
```

When I try to run this code, it gives this error:

```
MessageError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-1251d71a0a36> in <module>()
      7   json.dump(dict, f)
      8 
----> 9 files.download('sampleDictionary.json')
     10 f.close()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/files.py in download(filename)
    176       'port': port,
    177       'path': _os.path.abspath(filename),
--> 178       'name': _os.path.basename(filename),
    179   })

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/output/_js.py in eval_js(script, ignore_result)
     37   if ignore_result:
     38     return
---> 39   return _message.read_reply_from_input(request_id)
     40 
     41 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py in read_reply_from_input(message_id, timeout_sec)
    104         reply.get('colab_msg_id') == message_id):
    105       if 'error' in reply:
--> 106         raise MessageError(reply['error'])
    107       return reply.get('data', None)
    108 

MessageError: TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

[Click here to see the screenshot of my code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaYVz.png)

Please help me out

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you need to enable `third-party cookies` but for now it only works for Chrome browser, open

```
chrome://settings/content/cookies
```

make sure the option for `Block third-party cookies` is disabled and click `add` button in `Allow` section then add

```
colab.research.google.com
```

Comment: thankyou ... I had use files ui for this becuase of this

Comment: I did exactly what you said but still get the same error. am i missing sth?

Comment: Is it possible that is due to the use of Adblock? I allowed for cookies, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem (MessageError: TypeError: Failed to fetch) while using colab.

then, I split file operations into different code units in a colab notebook;
 I put file open, write, close in one code unit,
and use files.download() in the subsequent code unit.

the problem is gone!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the file is not finished being written by the time google attempts to "fetch" the file.
Simple solution:

```
with open('sampleDictionary.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(dict, f)
time.sleep(10)
files.download('sampleDictionary.json')
```

More complicated solution could be put a for loop with a try catch statement for files.download, and then put a sleep in the catch.  Keep a max loop time in case the file is never completed.

Comment: Is `time.sleep(10)` just an example and I need to use more than 10 seconds depending on the size of the file to download?

Comment: @AleB it is.  It is also possible that you need to run the files.download block in a separate code block after a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

After trying chrome cookies, tried except loop, nothing worked for me, so I changed the way that I get my files.
I used google drive file stream, it was very easy and efficient:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

it will ask you for authorization code, you can find it after visiting the corresponding url.

```
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/foo.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('Hello Google Drive!')
  #other instructions

drive.flush_and_unmount()
```

Answer (score 0):

It did not worked for me too. One way is to not use the

files.download(filename)

and simply going to the Files section and there will be your file. Right click and download it.

There is a > on the left of google colab editor and click it and there will be Table of Contents, Code Snippets and Files section.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem (MessageError: TypeError: Failed to fetch) while using colab.

then, I split file operations into different code units in a colab notebook;
I put file open, write, close in one code unit,
and use files.download() in the subsequent code unit.

Answer (score 0):

[ewwink's cookie solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582239/10361195) works.

However, even you set up cookie, that could be another problem if the colab notebook disconnect automatically, because you leave it for a long time. (for example, you run a series of code blocks, and it takes a long time before files.download run)

If that's the case, mount Google Drive(see medchik answer) instead could be a feasible alternative.