# Google Colab - downloads some files, TypeError: Failed to fetch on others

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I have a Google Colab notebook with PyTorch code running in it.
At the beginning of the train function, I create, save and download word_to_ix and tag_to_ix dictionaries without a problem, using the following code:

```
from google.colab import files

torch.save(tag_to_ix, pos_dict_path)
files.download(pos_dict_path)
torch.save(word_to_ix, word_dict_path)
files.download(word_dict_path)
```

I train the model, and then try to download it with the code:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_path)
files.download(model_path)
```

Then I get a `MessageError: TypeError: Failed to fetch`.
Obviously, the problem is not with the third party cookies (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581023/google-colab-file-download-failed-to-fetch-error)), because the first files are downloaded without a problem. (I actually also tried adding the link in my `Allow` section, but, surprise surprise, it made no difference.)

I was originally trying to save the model as is (which, to my understanding, saves it as a Pickle), and I thought maybe Colab files doesn't handle downloading Pickles well, but as you can see above, I'm now trying to save a dict object (which is also what word_to_ix and tag_to_ix) are, and it's still not working.

Downloading the file manually with right-click isn't a solution, because sometimes I leave the code running while I do other things, and by the time I get back to it, the runtime has disconnected, and the files are gone.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. What browser and browser version are you using? Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem?