# TypeError: Failed to fetch - Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am training my first neural network and want to write the accuracy of each iteration on nodes in a layer to a file. When there is only one iteration the file download and there is no problem, but when I increase the iterations the textfile that I am writing to seems to give me problems. Can anyone please explain to me why is it giving this error ,thank you?

I've resolved the issue by manually writing one accuracy value to the file along with the node amount, then downloading each file for an iteration. If I try to write the accuracy of each iteration to a single file for all iterations I receive the following error:

```
 MessageError      Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-31-4e05d4e1f010> in <module>()
       54     print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
      55   f.close()
 ---> 56 files.download('example.txt')

 MessageError: TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

#

**The code is as follow:**

```
  #Creating a file to store the accuracy values to
  with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:

    for n in range(1,3):
      model = keras.Sequential([
          keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
          keras.layers.Dense(64*n, activation=tf.nn.relu),
          keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
      ])
      model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])

      model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
      test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

      f.write(str(test_acc))
      f.write(",")
      f.write(str(n))
      f.write("\n")    
      print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
    f.close()
files.download('accuracy.txt')
```

I want to be able to run the neural network once, set it up for different nodes for the specified layers and at the end download one file with all the accuracy numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, so to speak. Each session in Google Colab lasts for 12 hours, an each instance of Google Colab that is opened starts the countdown to this session of 12 hours.

Solution: If I just close the tab that I am currently working on and wait about 10 minutes and open Google Colab again and run the neural network again from scratch it works 100%. So just close the tab and reopen and run if you get the error mentioned above :)

There could be another reason for this problem but for now this works for me.

Comment: answered at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581023/google-colab-file-download-failed-to-fetch-error/53582239#53582239